# Notification API: When user is off site?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to send browser notifications when a user has closed an application/site?

```
if(window.Notification && Notification.permission !== "denied") {
Notification.requestPermission(function(status) {  // status is "granted", if accepted by user
    var n = new Notification('Title', { 
        body: 'I am the body text!',
        icon: '/path/to/icon.png' // optional
    }); 
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the tab or page is open the user should receive the notification. What have you tried and what is not working exactly?

When the user closes the page it is not possible to send notifications anymore

Comment: The code above is fine, I was curious if there was a way to push notifications when a user has come away from the application.

Comment: When the user has closed the page you cannot send notifications through the notification API

Answer (score 0):

As of Chrome version 42, the Push API and Notification API are available to developers.
It utilises **service workers** to perform this. A service worker is a script that is run by your browser in the background, separate from a web page, opening the door to features which don't need a web page or user interaction.

For detailed information I would suggest you to check these out:

**Push Notifications On Google Chrome:**
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en

**Service Workers Tutorial:**
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/

**Detailed tutorial on how to use service workers for push notification:**
https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/12/15/push-notifications-service-worker

This also works on mobile devices.

Comment: Great references, do you have any examples (outside of the complete documentation)?

Comment: I've updated the answer please check. Let me know if it is of any help.